# Plupload: upload file directly to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file using plupload directly to my Amazon S3 bucket.

I don't know exactly how to adapt my Amazon S3 PHP code to my current php plupload code..

This is my Amazon S3 PHP code:

```
include('s3_config.php');
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = test_file;
if($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $file_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
{
$msg = "S3 Upload Successful.";
}
```

And this current PHP Plupload code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["name"])){

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// Settings
$targetDir = "HST_USR_UPLOADED_FILES__DIR/hst_uploaded_files";

//$targetDir = 'uploads';

$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}


$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;



// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir))
    @mkdir($targetDir);

// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
} else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');



// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);



            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {

    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);      


    ///---------------
        $filename = $fileName;
        $ext = substr($filename,strrpos($filename, "."));   

        if(preg_match('/\.(php|pl|py|cgi|asp|js)/i', $ext) && $ext != '.txt')
        {
            $ext = ".txt";
            $filename = $fileName.".txt";
        }


        $newFileName = substr(md5(strtotime('now').uniqid()), 0, rand(7,12)).strtotime('now');
        $newFileName = urlencode($newFileName).$ext;
        $filesize = filesize($filePath);
       ////---------------


       rename($filePath,  $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newFileName); 

    $code = substr(md5("f_".strtotime('now').uniqid()), 0, rand(5,12));
    while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM files WHERE `code` = '$code'")))
    {
        $code = substr(md5("f_".strtotime('now').uniqid()), 0, rand(5,12));
    }



    //insert file record into database
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$filename', '$newFileName', '$code', '$filesize', 0, 0, NOW(), NULL,  0, NULL, 'local', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL)"))
    {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
    }else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 420, "message": "File upload failed."}, "id" : "id"}'); 


}
?>
```

Comment: http://www.plupload.com/docs/Upload-to-Amazon-S3

Comment: I saw that, but really I don't know how to do it.. I solved this problem before but I'm idiot and I removed the changes :facepalm: now I don't know how to re-do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works.

```
<?php

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

include('s3_config.php');

if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, $bucket , $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
{
}

?>
```

**Final code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["name"])){

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
include('s3_config.php');
if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, $bucket , $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) )
{
    $code = substr(md5("f_".strtotime('now').uniqid()), 0, rand(5,12));
    while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM files WHERE `code` = '$code'")))
    {
        $code = substr(md5("f_".strtotime('now').uniqid()), 0, rand(5,12));
    }



    //insert file record into database
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$fileName', '$fileName', '$code', '$filesize', 0, 0, NOW(), NULL,  0, NULL, 'local', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL)"))
    {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
    }else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 420, "message": "File upload failed."}, "id" : "id"}'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: That's not uploading directly to S3, though. That's uploading to your server, which then uploads to S3. Unnecessary waste of bandwidth, time, and processing power.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was looking for a way to upload the files to my S3 bucket. Now I'm removing Plupload "code " part. I know it's a waste of bandwidth!